# Save a decimal value into a numeric field SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following in my code behind:

```
protected void SaveValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ArticleDBHQ article = new ArticleDBHQ();
        article.Weight = Convert.ToDecimal(tbWeight.Text);
}
```

In my `ArticleDBHQ` class the member variable `Weight` is as follows:

```
public class ArticleDBHQ : Entity
{
    private decimal? weight;

    public decimal? Weight
    {
        get { return weight; }
        set { weight = value; }
    }
}
```

In my data access layer, when I want to save this to my database, I call a stored procedure with a `SqlCommand` like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MODIFY_ARTICLE");
```

I pass the value:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@weight", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = (!Entity.Weight.HasValue ? SqlDecimal.Null : Entity.Weight.Value);
```

In my stored procedure, `Weight` is defined as follows:

```
    @weight DECIMAL, 
     ...
    p301_weight = @weight
```

And in the table `p301` the column `weight` is defined as `numeric`.

I can't change the type of the table, how can I save a `decimal` value to a `numeric`? As I understand (and I proved it) that it saves only the `integer` part, so instead of saving `0,5` is saving `1` (plus is rounding up).

Maybe a `convert`? But how and where.

**EDIT:**
field `weight` on table `p301` is declared as `numeric(9, 3)`

Comment: Multiple by 100 on Save and Divide by 100 on Retrieve. But this requires every process looking at field to understand that is what is going on.

Comment: the problem could be in your stored procedure parameter declaration. if you declare as just DECIMAL, it is just a whole number. a declaration of DECIMAL(10,2) gives you 2 decimal places.

Comment: Just `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` has a precision (after-the-comma digits) of **0** - no after-comma digits. Therefore, it only stores the "integer" part. You need to be **explicit** about what you need - use `DECIMAL(18,2)` or whatever makes sense - the first number is the number of **total digits** while the second number is the number of digits *after* the decimal point - in this case, 18 total digits, 2 of which after the decimal point (and therefore 16 before the decimal point)

Comment: one thought...what is the actual data type declaration in the table itself? Is it just NUMERIC with no parens afterwards? if that it the case it is essentially an INT, and you have to follow the advice of @ShawnC.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to put that on the thread, it is numeric(9, 3)
Let me edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the precision and scale on your decimal and numeric declarations in your stored procedure. If you don't when you assign 0.5 to your decimal it will already be converted to 1 and your numeric will also be one. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

So your stored procedure should look like:

```
 @weight DECIMAL(9,3), 
 ...
 p301_weight = @weight
```

The precision and scale you use should match what's set on the column in the table. If the table can only do whole numbers then you'll have to do something like what @Shawn C suggested and convert it to a whole number by multiplying then dividing to go the other way.

Comment: Space, I saw that previously some of my colleagues solve this problem like this:
They changed the type of weight as `nvarchar`, so is like follows
`@weight NVARCHAR(MAX),`

And make a convert;
`p301_weight = CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,3),@weight)`

Is this wrong? or is another way to do it?

Comment: @Nickso I wouldn't say it's wrong but in my opinion it's bad practice. You have an addition CONVERT that is unnecessary and you also open up the possibility of getting input that fails to CONVERT. What if someone calls the procedure with abcd?

Comment: So, even If I have a javascript that validates that textbox as numbers is not that good of a practice right?